# Where to find navigation bar metadata in experienceBundle

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, visualstudiocode, visual

I created a community using the Partner Central Template, added a few tabs besides home in the navigation Bar clicking on which opens up the salesforce object pages.
Now I can see those object pages inside "views" folder metadata but don't see the navigation menu item name being referenced inside the file or inside anywhere in the experiences folder.
I am trying to find where is the navigation bar-related metadata stored in the dx folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343863/i-want-to-package-unlocked-2gp-a-digital-experience-what-metadata-do-i-need), navigation menus are a separate metadata type that end up in the `navigationMenus` folder in an sfdx project structure, as a peer of the `experiences` folder.