# Can Communities be Packaged in 2nd Generation Managed Packages (2GP) in Salesforce?

Tags: community, managed-package, customer-community, community-builder

I am exploring the capabilities of 2nd Generation Managed Packages (2GP) in Salesforce and I am wondering if it's possible to package Communities along with their customizations and configurations in a 2GP.

Is it possible to package a Salesforce Community (including custom themes, branding, page layouts, components, etc.) in a 2GP?
If yes, what is the process for packaging Communities in 2GP? Are there any specific considerations or best practices to follow?

If not, are there any workarounds or alternative approaches to bundle a Salesforce Community as part of a 2GP package?

I would appreciate any insights, experiences, or resources related to packaging Communities in 2GP packages. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I went through a long discussion around this a couple of years back on the Partner forums with both Salesforce and other partners. The long and the short of it was this was strongly recommended against as this could cause a lot of problems.

Instead, therefore, we created an extension package of our managed package (i.e. a package using what our managed package has to offer) as a 2GP unlocked package. You can read about some of this [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343863/i-want-to-package-unlocked-2gp-a-digital-experience-what-metadata-do-i-need/343864#343864).